# How do you support release tags in github.io?

Tags: github, tags, release, github-pages

Github provides a great opportunity for javascript projects to expose themselves online. The solgan of this github pages technology is [Hosted directly from your GitHub repository. Just edit, push, and your changes are live](https://pages.github.com/). I have checked however, only `gh-pages` branch is visible. Yes, the slogan seems inapplicable for git standard `master` branch. Furthermore, there is a [release-tag standard, supported by github](https://pages.github.com/). It says that you solidify you releases marking them with release (version) tag. I can attach them in the `gh-pages` branch. But I see only the most recent commit available `live` and the question is `how do I make other releases available online also`?

*meta*: I realized that this question might be more appropriate to programmers since it does not discuss any coding. Should we migrate it there?

Comment: This isn't Github support

Comment: @jurgemaister This is not even git support, and not java support and not whatever support. SO supports nothing. Please give full information.

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered the a solution. Instead of marking release with tag, start every new release in new repository. You have [unlimited repositories](https://github.com/pricing), with every plan, even free one.